# For the Soulbolt's Double Shot blade skill, is the pair of ranged attacks made at the PC's highest BAB?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

Please elaborate on [Soulbolt's](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/archetypes/dreamscarred-press/soulbolt) Double Shot blade skill?

The skill simply states....

> **Double Shot:** As a standard action, a soulbolt can expend her psychic strike to make two ranged attacks with her mind bolt. The attacks do not deal the additional damage from psychic strike.

Is this pair of ranged attacks at the PC's highest BAB or do Two Weapon Fighting rules apply?

Answer (score 2):

It really ought to say, but in the absence of a statement to the contrary, no penalties (as from iteratives, two-weapon fighting, etc.) should be assumed, which means yes, at full BAB.